# An oriented 2-surface S such that at each point $p∈S$ , the principal curvatures of S at p are : $k_{1}(p)=1,k_{2}(p)=−1$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I was trying to find an example of an oriented 2-surface *S* $\in {\Bbb R}^3$ such that at each point $p \in S$ , the principal curvatures of S at p are : $k_{1} (p) = 1, k_{2} (p) = -1$ .

My attempt:

We have a well-known **result** stating : *On each compact oriented n-surface in ${\Bbb R}^{n+1}$,there exists a point p such that the second fundamental form at p is definite.*

Now by the definition of the second fundamental form to be definite at some $p \in S$, it follows that either both the principal curvatures are positive (i.e. $k_{1} (p) , k_{2} (p) >0 $) or both the principal curvatures are negative (i.e. $k_{1} (p) , k_{2} (p) <0 $).

So given our conditions that $k_{1} (p) = 1, k_{2} (p) = -1$ ($\forall p \in S$), the contra-positive statement of the above mentioned result yields us that our required S **cannot be compact** . And since we are in $\Bbb R ^3$ i.e. in Euclidean space, S **cannot be bounded**. (Since S is always closed)

I could think up to this point but haven't been able to come up with a concrete example, thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. You're right that such a surface, if it existed, would have to be noncompact. (And you can certainly find an example with those conditions at a *single* point $p$.)

There are two approaches here. One is to just work with the Codazzi-Mainardi equations and see whether such a surface can exist. More generally, you might try to classify non-umbilic surfaces first with *one* constant principal curvature, then with *both* principal curvatures constant. I refer you to exercises 16 and 17 on pp. 65-66 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).